# JNA. Fortran. Can we get COMMON variable with a jna interface

Tags: jna

We try to build tests in java from a fortran library and we would like to check COMMON variables. Is there a way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

If the symbol for it shows up in your shared library (use `nm` or `objdump` to look for it), then you can likely request its address using [`NativeLibrary.getGlobalVariableAddress()`](http://twall.github.io/jna/4.1.0/com/sun/jna/NativeLibrary.html#getGlobalVariableAddress(java.lang.String)), then extract its value using the appropriate `Pointer.getXXX()` method.

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked fine and has been very helpfull